# CreatedDate Not Available as Mapping Option in Salesforce Data Loader When Inserting New Records

Tags: data-loader, permission-sets, createddate

There's a need for me to load records in our SF sandbox wherein `CreatedDate` standard field in `Case` object must be inputted manually in csv file, instead of the system automatically setting itself. I already enabled the setting for it on **User Interface**, and also set **Audit Fields upon Record Creation** on  System Permission.

But still, `CreatedDate` field is not available as mapping option in Data Loader. Why is this so? Do I still need to contact Salesforce support for this?

Comment: what version of data loader?

Comment: I had the same problem, and didn't see any answers aside from the instructions that this is only available through API. I had to close data loader a couple of times before the audit fields showed up in the mapping section. Hope this saves someone some time.